# Transparency of a div class involving image_tag of rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

When using Paperclip for dynamic image processing on a rails application, i have tried with no positive result to include a div class(which set css background-color to transparent background-color: rgba(54,179,166, 0.6);) within the container that has an image processed by paperclip. 
The background-color property applied is instead, overshadowed by the image. See my code below

```css
.hottest .hottestImage
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;

}
 .hottest .hottestTitle
{
    
    background-color: rgba(54,179,166, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -350px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="hottest">
   <div class ="hottestImage">
     <%=  link_to image_tag @post_hottest.image.url(:preview) %>
   </div>
   <div class="hottestTitle">
      <h5><%= @post_hottest.title %></h5>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Paperclip has nothing to do with browser rendering. Pursue a css solution.

Comment: Debug with your browsers devtools.

Comment: Thanks Preciz, i ultimately concur to your submission. I have been trying to debug this for few days now.

Comment: You could look at other peoples examples on codepen, and edit them live. Nice way to learn: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/)